# C++: How to read and write multi-byte integer values in a platform-independent way?

Tags: c++, protocols, multibyte

I'm developing a simple protocol that is used to read/write integer values from/to a buffer.  The vast majority of integers are below 128, but much larger values are possible, so I'm looking at some form of multi-byte encoding to store the values in a concise way.

What is the simplest and fastest way to read/write multi-byte values in a platform-independent (i.e. byte order agnostic) way?

Comment: There's a lot to be said for text.

Comment: Just not very space-efficient, which likely is of some consequence for a binary protocol.

Comment: How much larger values? Arbitrary size, or is there a fixed limit? Signed or unsigned?

Comment: Decide on a platform independent format, and then store them in that format in a platform dependent way.

Comment: @DevSolar: If space is a factor then there's a lot to be said for using generic compression, *after* constructing the message. Fails if you're sending a lot of very small packets, of course, but saves you having to invent a different clever concise format for each field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[XDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_Data_Representation) format might help you there. If I had to summarize it in one sentence, it's a kind of binary UTF-8 for integers.

**Edit:** As mentioned in my comment below, I "know" XDR because I use several XDR-related functions in my office job. Only after *your* comment I realized that the "packed XDR" format I use every day isn't even part of the official XDR docs, so I'll describe it seperately.

The idea is thus:

- inspect most-significant bit of byte.

  - If it is 0, that byte *is* the value.
  - if it is 1, the next three bits give "byte count", i.e. number of bytes in value.

    - mask out top nibble (flag bit plus byte count), concatenate the appropriate number of bytes and you've got the value.

I have no idea if this is a "real" format or my (former) coworker created this one himself (which is why I don't post code).

Comment: XDR is interesting, but its minimum value size is 4 bytes, so I don't gain any space efficiency.

Comment: @Jen: D'oh... only now do I realize that the "packed XDR" format a coworker implemented apparently isn't part of the official XDR documentation...

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the following functions:

> htonl, htons, ntohl, ntohs - convert
>   values between host and network byte
>   order

```
   uint32_t htonl(uint32_t hostlong);
   uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort);
   uint32_t ntohl(uint32_t netlong);
   uint16_t ntohs(uint16_t netshort);
```

[`man byteorder`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/byteorder)

Comment: Don't know  if you were sarcastic ("...."), but if you weren't, glad to help! :-)

Comment: Fully serious, this addresses the endian issue in a standardized way (the more challenging part of my problem) -- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Text would be my first choice.  If you want a varying length binary encoding you have two basic choices:

- a length indication
- an end marker

You obviously make merge those with some value bits.

- For a length indication that would give you something where the length and some bits are given together (see for instance UTF-8),
- For an end marker, you can for instance state that MSB set indicates the last byte and thus have 7 data bits per byte.

Other variants are obviously possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Network Byte Order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_byte_order#Endianness_in_networking)

Answer (score 1):

Google's [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) provide a pre-made implementation that uses variable-width encodings.

Comment: Yes, protocol buffers are a great solution. I'm accepting DevSolar's answer because of the simplicity for my use case.